# Finding exact match for a string in a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to locate a word in a sentence based on an exact match using regex. For example:

```
Sentence1 = 'keyword1 is my keyword, keyworda , keyword- and keyword+'
Sentence2 = 'This is my keyword2 , keywordakeyword2andkeyword+'
Sentence3 = 'This is my keywordakeywordandkeyword2'
```

Another criteria is to check for occurrence of `keyword` at the beginning and middle of line.

Beginning of sentence/line regex

```
regex 1 = re.compile(r"^keyword1\b",re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
```

Here's the middle of a line regex:

```
regex2 = re.compile(r"(?!^)keyword2\b",re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
```

regex1 should return keyword1 and location in sentence 1

regex2 should return keyword2(2 occurence) and location in sentence 2. Notice second occurence of keyword2 ins sentence 2 is embedded between other strings

regex2 should return keyword2 from sentence 2 which occurs at the end of the line

I can probably use string comparison, but I need to get the location of `keyword` as well .. hence trying with regex.

Comment: why not `str.index("keyword")`?

Comment: Sorry, in a rush to edit made some mistakes.....have fixed the question

Comment: ok so if you want to match `keyword2` in the string `keywordakeyword2andkeyword` then it is not an exact match, it is just a substring.

Comment: Not really...I need to search for occurrence of keyword anywhere in the sentence when it is not first word in line or sentence and when it is first word in sentence

Comment: correct regex2.findall(sentence2) should return both keyword2 from sentence  2 however regex2.findall(sentence1) should not return any value since keyword2 is not present in sentence 1

Comment: So you need the second regex like`r'(?!^)\bkeyword2\b'`, right? I understand the first one works well.

Answer (score 2):

**Regex 1**

You may use this regex with look-arounds:

```
(?<!\S)keyword1(?!\S)
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/NBqfti/3/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\S)`: Assert that we don't have a non-whitespace character at previous position
- `keyword`: Match `keyword1`
- `(?!\S)`: Assert that we don't have a non-whitespace character ahead

---

**Regex 2**

```
(?!^)keyword2
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/NBqfti/4/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?!^)`: Assert that we are not at line start
- `keyword2`: Match `keyword2`

For coding I suggest using `re.search` function in `python` that returns and then `start()` and `end()` functions to get positions of the match.

Comment: This is close..but does not take into account where the keyword occurs..i.e. I need to check 2 cases where the keyword occurs in the beginning of the sentence and/or line and keyword is in the middle of line.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. Do you want to skip matching `keyword` at line start and line end? Can you edit question and clarify with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex

```
'keyword[\d]'
```

Compile the regex

```
regobj = re.compile('keyword[\d]')
```

To find the match at the beginning of sentence use **match** function called on the compiled object. It will return the matched object only if it finds the match in the beginning.

```
match = regobj.match(sentence1)
```

For finding match within the sentence use finditer function on the compiled object

```
it = regobj.finditer(sentence2)
match = it.__next__()
match.start()
```

start() function returns the starting index of the match and for the other match within the sentence call next() function on iterator object